# Pairs of Numbers into Groups

Tags: python-3.x

I have a CSV with two columns of numeric data which represent a "good match"
(e.g. 1 is a good match for 3, 1 is a good match for 70, 2 is a good match for 16)

I want to produce arrays of good matches as below.

```
Ex data:
    [1,3]
    [1,70]
    [2,16]
    [2,14]
    [2,24]
    [3,42]
    [3,23]

Ex output:
    [1,3,70]
    [2, 16, 14, 24]
    [3, 42, 23]
```

I am guessing something from itertools will do the job a whole lot more quickly than if or else, but can't find the right command or solution at the moment. Guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to collect the data linewise from the file and store it in a dictionary with the first number as key and a list as values. Same values for a key append to its list:

```
# create demodata
with open("f.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("1,3\n1,70\n2,16\n2,14\n2,24\n3,42\n3,23\n")

# process demodata
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

with open("f.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            k,v = map(int,line.split(","))
            d[k].append(v)

for key,values in d.items():
    print(key, values)

l = [ [k]+v for k,v in d.items()]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
# dictionary
1 [3, 70]
2 [16, 14, 24]
3 [42, 23]

# constructed lists from dict   
[[1, 3, 70], [2, 16, 14, 24], [3, 42, 23]]
```

You can construct the list you want from the dicts.

You can do the same without importing defaultdict, it will just be a tad slower:

```
d = {}

# same as above but replace d[k].append(v) with
d.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
```

Comment: thank you! very cool solution. I am just looking to get each value (n..66) assigned to one array, but because of small amount, I'm able to chop manually from this - very useful.